# GreenMail atomic getReceivedMessages() and purgeEmailFromAllMailboxes()

Tags: greenmail

Is there a way how to atomically receive messages from GreenMail and then purge those messages? I don't want to receive any message more than once. Something like `getReceivedMessagesAndPurge()`.

In my code, I want to write any email received by GreenMail to disk. My plan is to call `GreenMail.getReceivedMessages()` let say every second and write received messages to disk. And after that I need to call `GreenMail.purgeEmailFromAllMailboxes()` in order to write any message to disk only once. However there is a race condition which I don't know, how to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your own [MessageDeliveryHandler](https://github.com/greenmail-mail-test/greenmail/blob/master/greenmail-core/src/main/java/com/icegreen/greenmail/user/MessageDeliveryHandler.java) to do that.

Example:
https://github.com/greenmail-mail-test/greenmail/blob/master/greenmail-core/src/test/java/com/icegreen/greenmail/examples/ExampleUndeliverableTest.java